# Newbie Question - Finding Data Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably a very basic question but I can't figure out what to do.

I need to find a username from an id in an unrelated view.

In my app, my Orders have many Milestones. Each Milestone has an associated user although there is no relationship between the Milestone model and User model. In my Milestones form, I used the following to grab the user id's and display as a name:

```
<%= f.input :milestone_user, :as => :select, :multiple => false, :input_html => { :size => 1 }, :label => "", :collection => User.find(:all, :order => "name ASC") %>
```

However, in my show Milestone view, I can only see an id.

In order to display the name, I was trying something like this in the console to test:

```
@user = User.where(:id => 2)
```

But when I run:

```
@user.name
```

I get a no method error.

My questions are as follows:

1. Should I just make the milestones belong to Users as well?
2. If not, what's the best way to display the username?

-- UPDATE --

I'm totally lost about calling this in my view. If I use the suggestion below:

```
@user = User.find(2)
```

Actually what we need is something like:

```
@user = User.find(:milestone_user)
```

Where milestone_user is an integer. But that gives me errors. Very confused...

-- UPDATE 2 --

In my index view, I'm actually using table builder to display the information. For simplicity, I've deleted the extra code. My home#index view contains:

```
<% for milestone in orders %>
  <li><%= link_to milestone.name, milestone_path(milestone.id), { 'data-href' => milestone.notes, :class => 'selector' }  %></li> 
  <li><%= @users.name %> </li> 
<% end %>
```

And my home controller:

```
   @milestones = Milestone.all
   @users = User.find(params[:milestone_user])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `@user = User.where(:id => 2)` with `@user = User.find(2)`

UPDATE 2

The easiest way - remove `@users = User.find(params[:milestone_user])` from your home#index method and add correct your view file:

```
<% for milestone in orders %>
  <li><%= link_to milestone.name, milestone_path(milestone.id), { 'data-href' => milestone.notes, :class => 'selector' }  %></li> 
  <li><%= User.find(milestone.user_id).name %> </li> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked. Is this the best way to be doing it though??

Comment: How can I translate this to use the id from my milestones as well? Have tried User.find(:milestone_id) and User.find(params[:milestone_id]) but neither work

Comment: If you want to find a record by its id, its the best way. You should use User.find(params[:milestone_user]).

Comment: Tried that and I get an error: "Couldn't find User without an ID". I'm accessing on my home#index and have this in my home controller. Is that right? Jx

Comment: Please post your home#index source and Milestone model source

Comment: Wil add to question. Thanks jx

Comment: Updated answer. I dont know whats proper name of user field in Milestone model.

Comment: @Hck let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1799/discussion-between-jenny-blunt-and-hck)